# Setting login screen keyboard layout in Gnome (gdm)

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, keyboard-layout, gdm3

I'm running Arch Linux with the Gnome desktop environment. Using the Gnome settings I can add the dvorak keyboard layout and switch between with the shortcut key, but whenever start the computer the login screen has the qwerty keyboard set. As soon as I login, it's set back to dvorak though.

I've used `setxkbmap -layout dvorak` and `localectl set-x11-keymap dvorak` as detailed on the wiki [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_configuration_in_Xorg#Overview). 
But all they achieve is to remove the language toolbar from the login screen, so that I can't change to dvorak before login.

Where is the setting that allows me to specify the keyboard layout on the login screen?

**UPDATE**: Here is what my input sources settings look like:

[image]

Comment: I don't appear to have that button. See my updated question. Do you have any idea as to why it wouldn't be there?

Comment: Are you fully up to date ? Then check this out: [GDM defaults to en_US layout after upgrade to Gnome 3.16](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=747625)

Comment: Damn, it doesn't look like it's fixed yet. Do you know of any work arounds?

Comment: Adding a new user made the `Login Screen` button appear. I didn't even have to log out of my user. I have my login screen layout settings the same as my user settings, see [screenshot](http://imgur.com/a/frvFm). 

But the default layout on the login screen is still US, and once I login it automatically switches to Dvorak.

Comment: Yeah man, as per the bug report I linked to, if one of those layouts is US it will default to US. I don't know if there's a way to work around this... other than removing the US layout from the login screen layouts list...

Comment: Thanks for your help man. That does work, I guess I just gotta wait for the bug to be fixed. If you post an answer I'll accept :)

Comment: I posted my logs on the bug. Thanks for leading me to it.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using the Dvorak keymap on Gentoo for a very long time. There are three places where I set the keymap.

- In GNOME Settings -> Keyboard
- `/etc/conf.d/keymaps`
- `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-keyboard.conf`

***The Xorg conf file is the one that affects gdm login-screen***.  C̲o̲n̲t̲e̲n̲t̲ a̲s̲ f̲o̲l̲l̲o̲w̲s̲:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "system-keyboard"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        Option "XkbLayout" "us"
        Option "XkbVariant" "dvorak"
EndSection
```

The usual caveats, YMMV, after configuration just reboot and it should work.